# Is there a way to collect private 5G RSSI & Mac Address(or other identificator) on Android (or else)?

Tags: rssi, fingerprinting, 5g

I am currently exploring the usage of private 5G for indoor positioning instead of Wi-Fi fingerprinting.

However, I did not find much information on how to collect private 5G data (RSS and Mac Address).

I have download G-NetTrack but it seems only to provide the cellular 5G network from the telecom company my smartphone is connected to.

Is there any API in Android OS / iOS to collect those private 5G info?

Thanks in advance!